# Extracting information from site but there isn't any context

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

I imported selenium and it works well.

But there isn't any context (I am using visual studio code).

So what I exactly want is to extract some information from a site but it's dynamic (there are 8 odds XPath) So I want to make try and except like this

```
try:
    list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath1'))
except:
    list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath2'))
```

But I need to know the exception to make `except` for the other XPathes

So Is this right ???

```
try:
    list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath1'))

except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException :
    list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath2'))

except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException :
    list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath3'))
```

Comment: Use a loop instead?

Comment: Please share the url or relevant html, you might receive answers from OP, a better way of doing it.

Comment: https://www.auntyflo.com this is the domin

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am actually using a loop. the code above is just an example

Comment: normally it would need to use nested `try/except` inside `except`. `try: XPATH1 except: try XPATH2 except: try: XPATH3 except: ...`

Answer (score 1):

Normally it would need nested `try/except:`

```
try:
    list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath1'))
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath2'))
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath('XPath3'))
        except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
            print("ERROR")
```

So simpler can be to use `for`-loop to test different versions.

```
for path in ('XPath1', 'XPath2', 'XPath3'):
    try:
        list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath(path))
        break  # exit loop when path is working
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print("ERROR", path)
```

---

You can also use special construction `for/break/else` to run code in `else` when it doesn't run `break` inside `for`-loop

```
for path in ('XPath1', 'XPath2', 'XPath3'):
    try:
        list.append(browser.find_element_by_XPath(path))
        break  # exit loop when path is working
    except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        print("ERROR", path)
else:  # executed when it finish `for`-loop without using `break`
    print("Didn't find any path")
    #list.append(default_value)
```